# Is it possible for an android app from play store to be customised for particular users?

Tags: applications

Is it possible to customize a popular app downloaded from google play store for a user? Of late I have seen a few apps being weirdly customized in my android phone. Not sure if it is a form of hacking, or my phone has been compromised. Any thoughts that would help me diagnose would help.

Comment: What form of "customization" are you talking about?

Comment: They added another user in the settings

Comment: It's possible to customize apps on a broad case based on some factors, like language/locale, Android version, etc., but not directly per user. Probably would help if you can mention some of the apps (and their link to Play Store if possible)

Comment: In the google play app preferences, it was showing a different country and user name some time back until I corrected it

Comment: Do you mean another Android user (multi-user Android system) or another account in the account list you can view via settings menu? If it is the latter this is nothing special every app can add accounts and if it uses oAuth authentication via Google or Facebook and you allow it some of your data will be accessible to the app. But that is not a customization, this is simply a login like on a web page.

Comment: If you go to the Google play app settings you will see that It has your name, email id and country code. In that section it was showing the name, email id and country code of another user.